# Prolog : Simple question

Tags: prolog

I want to add any strings user entered into a list

```
run :- write('How many students you have: '),read(x),nl.
       enterNameOfStudents(x).

enterNameOfStudents(x) :- for(A, 1, x, 1),write('Please enter the names of students'),read(A),??????,nl,fail.
```

What do i put in the ?????? portion to ensure that whatever the user enter will go into a user-defined list which will be used for further processing later ? Please help. I have tried numerous stuff like append and other but it does not work :(

Comment: enterNameOfStudents(x,nameList) :- for(A, 1, x, 1),write('Please enter the names of students'),read(B),TempList = [B|nameList],nl,fail.

When the program loops i will only be able to store the last loop value. When i tried this nameList= [B|nameList] which is what i want prolog to do, it does not work. I am almost there anyone can help out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enterNameOfStudents(0, Names):-!.
enterNameOfStudents(X, [N|Rest]) :-    write('Enter a name: '), read(N), nl,
                   X1 is X - 1, enterNameOfStudents(X1, Rest).

run(Names) :- write('How many students you have: '),read(X),nl,
   enterNameOfStudents(X, Names).
```

You can construct the list recursively like this. You need to pass an argument to run so that you get back the full list at the end.